# Android Studio - "Unmappable character for encoding UTF-8"

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, macos, character-encoding

All was working fine and dandy with Eclipse in Windows until I switched to Mac OS X Yosemite, using Android Studio V1.0. I imported the project as a Non-Android Studio project since it was created with Eclipse, the import went fine and then Android Studio started showing this error all over the files :

```
error : unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

**EDIT:** Opening files directly into Sublime Text show no errors in foreign characters. Using `view.encoding()` inside ST's console I was able to see the file encoding, which was `Western (Windows 1252)`. I went to Android Studio and changed the encoding of the file to `windows-1252` and it's now working fine !
Is there a way to tell Android Studio to read the files in `windows-1252` and then **convert them to UTF-8** to keep the standard encoding format ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio : unmappable character for encoding UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677855/android-studio-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Adding the following to `build.gradle` solves the problem :

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
```

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this problem, too.
The reason for my problem is that I copy a file which is not encoded UTF-8 from Eclipse to Android Studio.
A solution to this problem is that:

1. Make sure the default file encoding of your Android Studio is UTF-8:
   Settings --> File Encodings, set  IDE Encoding, Project Encoding and Default encoding for properties files to UTF-8.
2. Copy your error file to a txt file and delete the error file.
3. Create a new file, its name is as the same as the deleted file.
4. Copy the content from the txt file to the new file.

Comment: @xikitidistant http://superuser.com/questions/69091/batch-change-encoding-ascii-files-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1

Answer (score 1):

For Android Studio 2.2 you have To add compile option in gradle file of your project:

**android {**
    ...
    ***compileOptions {
        encoding "ISO-8859-1"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }***
**}**