# how to display special characters using android studio

Tags: android

I can't display special characters like: "ü, ä, ö" etc, because I get the error: "unmappable character for encoding utf-8". I am using the Android Studio.

How to fix this?

Thanks a lot for your answers. But when I use the encoding part, then no errors appear anymore, but it looks like this:

[image]

The texts are defined in a `String[][]`

Comment: This has been answered before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525451/android-studio-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8

Answer (score 1):

You can show it as html:

```
    textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("ü, ä, ö"));
```

and you don`t need to change encoding.