# Android Tess-Two OCR unmappable character 'ﬁ'

Tags: java, android, ocr, tess-two

My android app has an OCR functionality using tess-two library. I have this issue in reading the String which contains "fi". After **baseApi.getUTF8Text()**, a method to get the recognized text by the OCR, the returned String in that ***"fi"***   is    ***"ﬁ"***  **<<<- - - Take a very close attention to that string.** It is not a 2-charactered String but a single-charactered String. You can reproduce that by copying and pasting. Now, I am thinking it might be an issue of UTF8 encoding or etc which I don't have enough knowledge with. When I tried to do **string.replace("ﬁ","fi")**, Android Studio builds with erors **unmappable character for encoding utf-8**. I tried searching in google but it recognize it as a regular "fi" not "ﬁ".

Is there any way I can fix this character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid recognizing the `ﬁ` ligature by blacklisting it before calling `baseApi.setImage`:

```
baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST, "ﬁ");
```

To prevent Android Studio from throwing the `unmappable character` error on your java code, convert your file encoding to UTF-8 by [choosing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677855/android-studio-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8) "UTF-8" from the selector near the bottom right corner of the Android Studio window.

Comment: So far this is fine :) I knew how the blacklist works but I never considered putting that character there because I thought It'l be a question mark when built.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I found, FWIW: the character 'ﬁ' is a ligature (more at: [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI' (U+FB01)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb01/index.htm))

Here's a quick and dirty program to find and replace 'ﬁ' with any other characters:

```
public class LigatureFI
{

    static char ligature_fi = 0xFB01;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sligature_fi = Character.toString(ligature_fi);
        String string = new String("ﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁﬁ");
        System.out.println(string);
        string = string.replaceAll(sligature_fi, "FI");
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}
```

If your IDE complains about 'ﬁ' not being in the cp1252 charset, save as UTF8.

HTH.

Comment: Your method doesn't work, the result is a string of question marks.

Comment: I think this his happening because `fi` is not a known character. I'm assuming your replace function is not working, so the `fi` is still there and since IntelliJ can't output it properly it's replacing it with a question mark.

Comment: Method works on my machine, result is "FIFIFIFIFIFIFIFIFIFIFIFIFIFIFI"

Comment: That is strange. I tried it with '\uFB01' instead, which is the proper way to refer to it in Java and it still didn't work. It's weird because if I copy and paste that in IntelliJ the paste will give the "ﬁ" character, not the coding, so I know that part is right. When I tried `ﬁ == '\uFB01'` it also gave me `true`, but when I tried `string.charAt(0) == '\uFB01'` it gave me false, even though I copied the same character "ﬁ" to make the string. I'm not sure what's going on.