# How to show non-English characters correctly with AlertDialog without using a string resource

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

The question is best explained with the following simple code:

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button
ad.setMessage("Italiano è" + "   "  + getString(R.string.debug));
ad.show();
```

where R.stringdebug is exactly the same as "Italiano è".  The following is a screenshot of the display:

[image]

You can see that the character "è" is displayed correctly only if it is in a string resource.

How can it be displayed correctly in a hard-coded string?

Edit:
The result of of using ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 for the java source code file:[image]

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but I think you should always use string resources, no?

Comment: It's probably a problem with the source code file character encoding, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24568901/8085849

Comment: @Sweeper the app has a very large string resource file.  It would take too much space to explain why hard-coded string is preferred in this case. I edited the question to show the result of using ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This One to handle it, not Tested this code but hope it will work
>   in your case

```
Html.fromHtml("Italiano è");
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  Unfortunately, the result is the same.