# All android project file encoded wrongly

Tags: android, android-studio, encoding

All my android studio file is not showing original code. All java and XML file affected. When I open a file it shows "File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8'. I tried to reload in another coding but problem not resolved. I can see code in Notepad but not in android studio.

CustomApplication.java Original Code showing in Notepad

```
package satlaa.desijewellery.utils;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

public class CustomApplication extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "hi"));
}
}
```

In Android Studio

```
AAPT               ,  �       
&layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material 
"�C:\Users\Anjaan\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-
```

27.1.1.aar\11bca4c6723b60847116b8b51872d16b\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_title_m 
    aterial.xml*
     id/alertTitle-*
     id/titleDividerNoCustom8*
    id/title_template*
    id/topPanel
    �
    9
   android*http

I can even set here as code.
[image]

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677855/android-studio-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8

Comment: Show the error.

Comment: Attact image bro.. i just want to see how your problem looks like.

Comment: yes, provide image please.

Comment: please invalidate cache and restart android studio from file option

Comment: @SyedQasimAhmed did that. Not solved

Comment: I solved this error by invalidating cache and restart

Comment: May be, reinstalling android studio will solve your problem, give a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to :

`File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings`, find `File Encodings`, change Project Encoding to `System-Default` and the other settings as follows:

[image]

If this didn't help, try reinstalling the Android Studio (or install the latest version if you already don't use it).

Comment: Have you tried using other encodings? Use *Reload in another encoding* and choose another one to see if that effects. You can however, reinstall or install the latest version of android studio without using the old config.