# is Android Studio corrupting my project files?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two very annoying bugs which is ocurring in the project I am working with. Android Studio keeps overwritting code from many classes using another classes inside the same project.

1 - File contents are wrong
2 - The encoding inside some files seems to have strange characters

For you to have an idea, I will upload a few screenshots below:

*This one was supposed to be an enumeration class.*
[image: buggy class android]

*This class was duplicated in another class (overwritting)*
[image: duplicate class Android]

*This class is all messed up and has strange characters...*
[image: wrong encoding android]

At first, I thought the files were really corrupted, then I opened them in their respective folders to check whether it was only in Android Studio or not, and they are completely normal there.

*ActivitiesMode.java*

[image]

*ReviewDatesRecyclerView (duplicated file)*
[image]

*ReviewEditRecyclerViewAdapter (UTF Strange characters)*
[image]

Does someone has an idea on what can be happening?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. At once i re-install Android Studio then it will solved but later on again occur same problem. Maximum files are corrupted. right now i have changed my workspace and import project it will work.

Comment: @VasudevVyas check my own aswer on this post. I think it's something related to old configurations on Android Studio itself, because it occured after updating to the latest version.

Comment: What version of AS are you using? Has this started happening after an update?

Comment: @lelloman AS 3.3.1. Exactly, after upgrading it from 3.3.0 to 3.3.1 the problem started. Thankfully, I managed to solve that.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents/54509482#54509482

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve all these problems by completely reinstalling Android Studio 3.3 and deleting all the configurations and related folders.

At first, I've reinstalled the IDE, but the same problem occured. Then I tried to follow instructions about encoding on this answer "[Android Studio : unmappable character for encoding UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677855/android-studio-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8)"

*None of these had any effect.*

**Here's how I fixed it:**

- Uninstalled Android Studio
- Deleted Android Studio SDK
- Deleted .gradle, .android, .AndroidStudio3.3 folders located in *C:\Users\MyUserName*
- Fresh Installed Android Studio 3.3
- Opened it's encoding settings on File > Settings > File Encodings
- Changed all encoding types to UTF-8 (Global, Project and Default)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Should delete:**

1) C:\Users\cc.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches

2) all .iml files in your project folder

3) .idea with .gradle folders.

Comment: Thanks man i lost lake a hour trying to fix this i update android studio to the latest and it started to give me these stupid encoding problems

Comment: The last 2 Points did the job. ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Close project
2. Rename the project root folder name (e.g. Old "Android-Project" new "Android Project") and reopen the project it will solve the problem.