# I cant get cyrillic letters from .properties file in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I use libGDX with java and android studio and I want to make localization. I use Bundle from libGDX but I can't get cyrillic letters(I get only "?"s): [printing message from bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNCwP.png)

I tried to change encoding to windows-1251, cp866 and UTF-8(It's default) but it doesn't work. That's my code if it can help(other parts of code are default for libGDX):

```
    private I18NBundle myBundle;
private Locale locale;

@Override
public void create () {
    locale = new Locale(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("bundle_" + locale);
    myBundle = I18NBundle.createBundle(file, locale);
    
    Gdx.app.log("message", myBundle.get("button.start"));
}
```

Comment: I'm still not good with boundle, but I have some experience with unicode. Logs and console  usually have problems displaying non ASCII characters. Can I suggest you to try to print the into a control (like a text control or a label)? Perhaps it's just the media you printed to (I did my experiment with Japanese and had a similar problem).

Comment: What happens in your IDE with ```System.out.println("\u0440\u0443\u0301\u0441\u0441\u043A\u0438\u0439")``` ?

Comment: @g00se  I get "��?�����"

Comment: I suspect then that your IDE is not configured as UTF-8 and/or that its font does not have Cyrillic glyphs

Comment: @g00se when I set UTF-8 in android studio my cyrillic letters in files become "�"

Comment: What about the literal I gave you - is that OK?

Comment: @g00se I changed settings in Android studio, changed fonts(but default supports cyrillic) and it doesnt help

Comment: What does ```System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));``` print?

Comment: @g00se it doesnt change when I change property file encoding in settings. In settings property files have windows-1251 encoding with "disabled for Properties" adding

Comment: @g00se when I add UTF-8 encoding in constructor it doesnt work

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: @g00se  only windows-1251

Comment: Your system encoding obviously supports Cyrillic. Try forgetting Unicode and set everything to Windows-1251

Comment: @g00se and what should I do?

Comment: I just said in my last  ;)

Comment: @g00se I set windows-1251 everywhere and nothing changed

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677855/android-studio-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8) might help. In your case, it would be Windows-1251 in theory

Comment: @g00se when I read file using standart libGDX file reading I get letters codes like \u0418\u0413\u0420\u0410\u0422\u042C but steel not letters

Comment: *What* is it reading? Can you post a link to the actual file?

Comment: there's also [fhis](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/1827)

Comment: @g00se I fix it, I updated studio and now there is a text on textButtons, thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you got it working